# ion-input with floating label placeholder colour is not changing in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, placeholder

I want to change the placeholder colour of ion-input but i'm unable to change the placeholder colour. I have ion-input with floating label. here is my workaround...

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>first Name</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

what i have tried and not working...

```
1) $text-input-placeholder-color
```

2)

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: pink;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: pink;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: pink;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: pink;
}
```

3)

```
::placeholder {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

but nothing is working. can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a placeholder. It is still a `ion-label`

To change the style of a floating ion-label,

Add this to your `variable.scss`

```
$label-ios-text-color: blue;
$label-md-text-color: blue;
$label-ios-text-color-focused: blue;
$label-md-text-color-focused: blue;
```

or edit your `.scss`

```
.label[floating],
.label[stacked],
.input-has-focus .label[floating] {
    color: blue ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ion-item.item-has-focus > ion-label {
      color: red ;
  }`

Comment: please provide more details to your answer, what does your code or how does it answer OP question

Answer (score 0):

Just giving out a somewhat simpler solution for the problem.
When you have multiple rules setting a property, i.e `color: red;`, CSS will apply that one that has more "priority". None of the selectors will have more priority than the keyword `!important`.

```
ion-label {
   color: your-awesome-color-here !important;
}
```